# maven: create a jar from generated sources and add it as a dependency before compiling

Tags: java, maven

I would like to include a jar file instead of adding sources. The end result would be like adding a dependency and my war file gets a extra jar in WEB-INF/lib instead of extra classes in WEB-INF/classes.

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.8</version>
          <configuration>
              <sources>
                  <source>target/generated-sources/wsimport</source>
              </sources>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>add-source</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I was thinking something like:

Step 1) generate source

Step 2) generate a jar file from target/generated-sources/wsimport

Step 3) install it into local repository before compiling (mvn install:install-file -Dfile=MyWsImport.jar)

Step 4) Add MyWsImport.jar dependency

Step 5) Compile

Comment: While this is possible, it seems like you're making life very difficult for yourself. In maven projects, it's conventional to have one project per artifact, and it'd be much easier to simply create a new project for the jar you want to build, and add it as a dependency to the war. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: 2 projects is ok as long its is transparent for the user, meaning that they can just do a maven compile like the current setup that just add sources. If it is too difficult I just stick with adding sources :)

Comment: no problem with compile on single project only. Please note, in Maven there are dependencies, inheritence, but also submodules. Once you'd go for having one project holding others as submodules, you can still build this single one to propagate all the work to it's submodules. Just google it, or check one I googled now: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects

Comment: did try modules and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Peter Butkovic above using modules worked.

https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.google.appengine.gcl</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcl-11</artifactId>
    <version>0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>rs</module>
        <module>ws</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```